# How can I solve this basic recurrence $T(n) = \sqrt{n} \cdot T(\sqrt{n}) + n^2$?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Could someone post the *detailed* steps for calculating a *tight* upper bound of the following recurrence?

$$T(n) = \sqrt{n} \cdot T(\sqrt{n}) + n^2$$

Comment: Could you show *in detail* what you have tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: I let $\ell := \log n$ and tried to solve $X(\ell) = \ell / 2  \cdot X(\ell / 2)$.

Comment: If $T(x)<cx^2$ for $x<n$ and  $n>(\frac c{c-1})^2$, then $T(n)<\sqrt ncn+n^2<cn^2$

Comment: When $n = 1$ , $ T(1) = T(1) + 1$ i.e. $0 = 1$

Answer (score 0):

Shaving the squared root seems to work out, namely set

$$S(n) := \frac{T(n)}{\sqrt{n}} = T(\sqrt{n}) + \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n}} = T(n^{1 / 2}) + n^{3 / 2} = T(2^{k / 2}) + 2^{3k/2} \text{ via the substitution $k := \log_2 n$}$$

and solve the shorted recurrence $R(k) = R(k / 2) + 3k / 2$ via the method of the recursion tree to get a recursion tree with node weight equals $3k / 2$ and tree height $\log_2 k$, i.e. $R(k) \in \mathcal{O}(\frac{3k}{2} \log_2 k)$, since the overall weight at every level is $3k / 2$. Thus, $S(n) = 3 / 2 \cdot \log_2 n \cdot \log_2 \log_2 n$ and finally

$$T(n) = \sqrt{n} \cdot \Big (\frac{3 \log_2 n}{2} \cdot \log_2 \log_2 n\Big)$$

and it's gone. I hope that someone proofread it.

Answer (score 0):

As

$$
T\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right)=\sqrt{n}T\left(2^{\log_2 \sqrt{n}}\right)+n^2
$$

or

$$
T\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right)=\sqrt{n}T\left(2^{\frac 12\log_2 n}\right)+n^2
$$

calling now $\mathcal{T}(\cdot) = T\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right)$ and $z = \log_2 n$ we follow with

$$
\mathcal{T}(z)=2^{\frac z2}\mathcal{T}\left(\frac z2\right)+2^{2z}
$$

now calling $\mathbb{T}(\cdot) = \mathcal{T}(2^{(\cdot)})$ and $u = \log_2 z$ we follow with

$$
\mathbb{T}(u)=2^{\frac{2^u}{2}}\mathbb{T}(u-1)+2^{2\times 2^u}
$$

with solution

$$
\mathbb{T}(u) = C_02^{2^u}+2^{2^u}\sum_{k=0}^u 2^{2^{k-1}}
$$

now going backwards we get

$$
T(n) = C_0 n + n\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\log_2(\log_2 n)}2^{2^{k-1}}\right)
$$

hence $T(n) \approx \mathcal{O}\left(n^2\right)$

Comment: Please try to develop the transition from the third to the second line (from the bottom to the top) more thoroughly.